# Image reload causes flicker only in firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, refresh

I'm creating a website which streams real time data images from a remote system and displays them on the website. These images change at the remote site every 5 seconds and hence we auto reload/refresh these images.
 **PROBLEM** : The image refresh takes place correctly & smoothly on IE and chrome, but in Firefox every auto refresh causes a flicker. This is unwanted behavior. How do I fix this? 
**PS** I am using joomla articles within which I embed the required javascript

```
     <center>  
     <img id="pic" src="images/CB1.jpeg" border="0" width="700" height="700"/></center>
     <script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript">
      function refresh() 
       {         
      document.images["pic"].src = "images/CB1.jpeg" + "?" + new Date().getTime();
       }
      window.onload=function(){
      setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 5000 ); 
      }
     </script>
```

This is script is embedded in joomla articles. The image is around 300~350 KB.

Comment: Have you got a demo page we can take a look at?

Comment: You could put two `<img>`s above each other, reload the bottom (invisible) one and move it to front when it's loaded via `onload`. I belive the flicker comes from FF already rendering the image while it's still being loaded.

Comment: @scourou thank you for the quick reply. I'm sorry I cannot provide with the website url as the site is on a local machine in my office and I've no domain as of now. Hence I'm adding the code that I'm using.If you place this code in a normal html page it gives the same behaviour kindly help. Thank you

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Hi, thnks for the reply. Can you please explain what you mean by move the hidden <img> tag to front, so that I can look it up on the net . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to test on your machine, I can't say for certain but I think Cobra_Fast is correct in that the image is rendering before it's finished loading. To get around this, make sure you don't replace the old image until after the new image has finished loading. This should work:

```
<img id="pic" src="images/CB1.jpeg">

<script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript">
function refresh() {
    // create new image obj
    var image = new Image();

    // replace the existing image once the new image has loaded
    image.onload = function () {
        document.images["pic"].src = image.src;
    }

    // set the source of the new image to trigger the load 
    image.src = "images/CB1.jpeg" + "?" + new Date().getTime();
}

window.onload=function(){
    setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 5000 ); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: hi,I tried running the code you provided. It still flickers :( Do I use your code as is, or do I need to customize it? Sorry if my question sounds stupid. I'm not really well versed with javascript!!

Comment: I tested this in FF with a few test images, and I didn't get a flicker - just a pretty instant change. Maybe it isn't an issue with the loading. Can you upload the images you are using somewhere so I can test with them? Just two sequential images should do.

Comment: thank you for taking out the time to test and letting me know. I'm facing a dilemma here. The script gives a flicker on two test m/cs but on the 3rd it works fine as you say. I donot know what maybe going wrong. The main office machine is a windows 2008 r2 server running a 18.0.1 Firefox on it...Thanks for all the help.

Comment: That's very odd. I'd take a look at the differences between the machines. Are the FF versions identical? It might even be a graphics rendering difference. Suffice to say, if it's working on some but not others, then the issue is probably not the code.

Comment: I tested on a couple of machines and I find what you say is true. The flicker is present only on the webserver machine and none of the client machines. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I have a similar problem.Like you asked to not replace the old image until after the new image has finished loading, I am doing the same but even inside the load callback the new image is not yet rendered

Comment: It could happen because of this bug of Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705826